# How to properly store the output of host command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, ip-address, hostname

I'm trying to store ip addresses given by host, but host actually gives a string saying *host-name* has address *ip-address* as many times as many addresses it finds. So my question is can I somehow access the addresses only, without splitting strings and looking for ip addresses? What I've tried so far looks like this

```
ip=$(host "$candidate")

IFS="s " read -ra ADDR <<< "$ip"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

where $candidate holds the host name, but I couldn't really put it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: if you have ssh access keys set from source/target candidate server for password less access, you can do: ip=$(ssh user@$candidate "hostname -i")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different DNS lookup tool, such as dig:

```
$ foo=($(dig google.com +short))
$ printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
74.125.228.196
74.125.228.206
74.125.228.200
74.125.228.198
74.125.228.193
74.125.228.192
74.125.228.199
74.125.228.197
74.125.228.201
74.125.228.195
74.125.228.194
```

If you must use `host`, then you will have to do string splitting:

```
foo=()
while read -r _ _ _ addr; do
    foo+=("$addr")
done < <(host -t A google.com)
printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
```

Comment: With bash 4 or newer, `readarray` is available: `readarray -t foo < <(dig google.com +short)`; this skips some bugs your first answer has around glob expansion and odd IFS values. That said, +1 for suggesting `dig +short`.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the IP address using **parameter expansion/substring extraction** as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 
    array+=( ${line##* } )      # substring extraction for IP only
done < <(host -t A google.com)

for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

**Output:**

```
$ bash getip.sh
173.194.115.36
173.194.115.35
173.194.115.40
173.194.115.37
173.194.115.34
173.194.115.39
173.194.115.41
173.194.115.46
173.194.115.33
173.194.115.38
173.194.115.32
```

You can accomplish the same thing with **string substitution:**

```
    array+=( ${line//*\ /} )      # string substitution for IP only
```

Comment: Quote your expansions -- `for i in "${array[@]}"`, or else you've written an equivalent to `for i in ${array[*]}`.

Comment: similarly: `array+=( "${line##* }" )`, if you want one array entry per line.

Comment: Alternately: `while IFS=' ' read -r ip _; do array+=( "$ip" ); done` strips off everything after the first ` ` implicitly, without the PE needed, by putting that content into `_`.

Comment: Yes, agree, but the output from hosts is of the form `google.com has address 173.194.115.41` which would lead to a `read -r _ _ _ IP` as indicated in the other answer.